# Events wont appear in chart

Tags: java, reactjs, postgresql

I'm creating a climate-change based project and I'm having problems with one of my visuals. The following chart should show an graph with red and black lines, which it does correctly. However, it should also show ''events'' as yellow triangles at the top of the lines but they won't appear whatever I do. Does anyone else notice the problem?

V3.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import axios from "axios";
import { Chart as ChartJS } from "chart.js/auto";
import Constants from "../Constants.json";


function V3() {

    const [showDescription, setShowDescription] = useState(false);

    const [globalData, setGlobalData] = useState({});

    const getGlobalData = () => {
        axios.get(Constants.API_ADDRESS + "/v3global").then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);

            // Multiply yearG by 1000
            const modifiedData = response.data.map((item) => ({
                ...item,
                yearG: item.yearG * 1000,
            }));

            setGlobalData(modifiedData);
        })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getGlobalData();
    }, []);


    const [carbonData, setCarbonData] = useState({})
    const getCarbonData = () => {
        axios.get(Constants.API_ADDRESS + "/v3carbon").then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            setCarbonData(response.data);
        })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        getCarbonData();
    }, []);


    const [eventData, setEventData] = useState({})
    const getEventData = () => {
        axios.get(Constants.API_ADDRESS + "/v3event").then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            setEventData(response.data);
        })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        getEventData();
    }, []);

    const data = {
        datasets: [
            {
                showLine: true,
                label: "Carbondata",
                type: 'line',
                data: carbonData,
                borderColor: "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
                backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
                parsing: {
                    xAxisKey: "yearc",
                    yAxisKey: "carbondata",
                },
                pointRadius: false,
                xAxisID: "x",
            },
            {
                label: "Globaldata",
                type: 'line',
                data: globalData,
                borderColor: "rgb(7, 0, 0)",
                backgroundColor: "rgb(7, 0, 0)",
                parsing: {
                    xAxisKey: "yearG",
                    yAxisKey: "global",
                },
                pointRadius: false,
                yAxisID: "y1",
                xAxisID: "x",


            },
            {
                label: "Event",
                showLine: false,
                data: eventData,
                borderColor: "rgb(255, 213, 0)",
                backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 213, 0)",
                parsing: {
                    xAxisKey: "year",
                    yAxisKey: "value",
                },
                pointRadius: 6,
                pointStyle: 'triangle',
                xAxisID: "x1",
            },

        ],
    };

    const optionsV3 = {
        responsive: true,
        sacked: false,
        plugins: {
            legend:
            {
                position: "top",
            },

            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Evolution of global temperature over the past two million years",
                font: {
                    size: 20
                },
            },
        },

        scales: {
            y:
            {
                type: 'linear',
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: "Carbon",
                },
                position: "left",



            },
            y1: {
                type: "linear",
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: "Global",
                },
                position: "right",
                grid: {
                    drawOnChartArea: false,
                },

            },


            x: {
                type: "linear",
                time: {
                    unit: "year"
                },

                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Thousands years before present'
                },

                reverse: true,
            },
            x1: {
                display: false,
            }
        },
    };


    const toggleDescription = () => {
        setShowDescription(!showDescription);
    };


    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Visualization 3</h1>
            <div className="button-container">
                <button onClick={toggleDescription} className="btn btn-outline-primary-mt2">{showDescription ? "Hide description" : "Show description"}</button>
            </div>
            <div className="chart-container">
                {showDescription ? <div className="card mt-4" style={{ width: "24rem" }}>
                    <div className="description">
                        <h5 className="description-title">Description</h5>
                        <p className="description-text">This chart shows Evolution of global temperature over the past two million years.</p>
                        <p>You can also see some of important milestones about human evolution that are related to Co2 and temperature changes.</p>
                    </div>
                    <h6 className="description-sources">Sources:</h6>
                    <p> <a href="https://climate.fas.harvard.edu/files/climate/files/snyder_2016.pdf/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" className="card-link">Description </a></p>
                    <p> <a href="http://carolynsnyder.com/publications.php" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" className="card-link">Datasets</a></p>
                    <p> <a href="https://www.southampton.ac.uk/~cpd/history.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" className="card-link">Human Evolution</a></p>
                </div> : <Line data={data} options={optionsV3} alt="chart"></Line>}
            </div>
        </div>

    );
} export default V3;
```

If required, I can also provide code from the backend but I think the problem is at V3.js

Thank you for your time

I've tried different methods in parsing and changing values in many places without any results